# Textarea Cutoff in PHP $_POST array

Tags: php, arrays, string, post, superglobals

**My textarea on a webform [using POST method] is getting cutting off at 1024 characters**.

The field does not have a max length attribute set and will allow over 1024 characters to be entered.  However, when I view the $_POST array in Eclipse and try to insert into Database, I can see it is not the entirety of the user's input.

What is the root cause of this issue?  Is there an inherent limitation that I am unaware of?  I can't seem to find any documentation on this issue.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your database column's display width is set at 1024. Do a simple query, output the data on the page, and you will see that the user's post is intact. If it's truncating at the `$_POST` check out your `php.ini` for `memory_limit`, `post_max_size`.

Comment: He said when he views it in Eclipse - I'm assuming `var_dump()` or `print_r()`. I got the impression it's truncated before the PHP script starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was not a limitation in the database after all.  The 'variable' window in Eclipse will only show a maximum of 1024 characters, per field, which is what threw me off.  There were other issues with my insert statement that made me think that the Eclipse limitation was the root; however, after using @George Brighton's suggestion of `print_r($_POST)`, I realized my error.

Answer (score 2):

Is your [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) directive in php.ini set to 1024? The default is 8M.

The setting can't be modified at runtime, but if you have access to `.htaccess` or similar, add a line like this:

```
php_value  post_max_size  8M
```

Comment: checked the post_max_size and it was defaulted to 8M.  I tried bumping to 16M and am still having the same issue.

Comment: Is the definitely nothing else in the way - if you just put <?php print_r($_POST); at the top of a page and submit a form to it, is the data still truncated?